# How to get the "check" next to text messages without being notified?

Tags: notifications, sms

I have an HTC Incredible 2. The default is NOT to notify you when your message has been delivered.

I can go into settings and tell it to notify me. After doing so, it puts a checkmark next to the message when its been delivered -- That I like. However, it also "alerts" me with a notification in my notifications bar that it has been delivered -- I find that annoying.

Is there anyway to get the checkmark indicating it was delivered without the notification alert?

Comment: This is probably an HTC Sense thing that you can't change. On my G2, with the "vanilla" Android interface, it displays a small toast message that disappears after a few seconds.

Comment: @thunsaker, thanks, you're probably right. This is my first Android phone so I can't compare with others.

Answer (score 1):

John as @thunsaker states this a HTC Sense mod and unfortunately cannot be changed.

You could look at rooting your phone and putting a vanilla ROM of Android on or the fully customisable Cynogen Mod 7, that way you can take back the control HTC stole ;-).

A place to start would be http://www.android.modaco.com

Answer (score 1):

Rather than modify your ROM and switch over to CyanogenMod, why not simply use an alternative SMS app like Handcent SMS or GoSMS. Both have customizable options for Sent message notifications, including vibrate pattern options.